How is angular momentum associated with wave functions and electrons?
While I came across the quantum mechanical model of an atom, I learnt that the concept of angular momemtum remains relevant for an electron and is also associated with the magnetic quantum number, what I don't get is that how is this concept apply to an electron despite the lack of a classical representation of electrons revolving around the nucleus,I noticed a similar question on Stack Exchange related to quantum mechanics and concepts I'm unfamiliar with. I'm looking for a clear understanding based on reasoning and quantum mechanics, without diving into complicated math or abstract ideas.

Quantum mechanics is complicated math.

There is a classical analogue to angular momentum in electron orbitals. Did you study circular motion in you Physics courses? Think of the Bhor-Sommerfeld model. Anyhow, I hope it become clearer when you study the solutions of the Schrödinger equation for an hydrogenoid atom.

@PAEP Except that analogue makes things more confusing. The minimum value of angular momentum is zero, which cannot be conveyed by an orbital model.

@Zhe of course the classical analogue has plenty of limitations , but analogies are useful if used with due consideration. Maths are fine, but as a Chemist you need to build intuitions. How do you introduce the quantum calculation of angular momentum operators that you will need to write the atomic and molecular Hamiltonians?

There are basically two approaches to quantum mechanical models. One involves very complex math. The other   is based on oversimplified classical analogies that just partially fit.

This issue is that nature can be described intwo ways, as observable quanta, or as calculated waves. That duality does defy common sense, and is not susceptible to simplistic explication. To quote Εὐκλείδης, "There is no royal road to geometry."

This question is similar to: Why is there an orbital angular momentum if the electron isn't properly revolving around the nucleus?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@PAEP Very few of the subject experts admit any real intuition for QM. In my experience, you look at the conclusions from the mathematics, and accept those as part of the model, however non-intuitive they are (or don't, it's just a model). Some of the most trivial conclusions from macroscopic systems  (e.g., pigeonhole principle) fail to have reasonable quantum analogies. You introduce those operators exactly as their authors did, by conceptual necessity. There is no stipulation that the workings of nature can be made clear to everyone.

I just came across that other question and realized that angular momentum, as defined, is merely a property of the system derived from solving the Schrödinger equation. While an electron can be detected here or somewhere else without having traversed the space between the points after each time interval Δt, it isn't actually orbiting in the traditional sense. So why is this property referred to as 'angular momentum'? It seems that every time we consider it, we can't but think of something around around something as in the 'classical sense'

"why is this property referred to as 'angular momentum'" – Classical angular momentum obeys certain commutation laws. Quantum angular momentum is basically defined as anything that obeys the same laws, even if it's not spinning in the classical sense.

@orthocresol So only because it obeys some similar properties and analogous to some extent, it's termed 'angular momemtum', but it's entirely different from the standpoint of classical physics?
